# Fulltext search in MySQL and PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm currently trying to perform a search over 2 fields in my MySQL table (text type) using PHP.

```
SELECT  * FROM content_items WHERE MATCH (content,name) AGAINST ('".urldecode($_REQUEST['term'])."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I'm always getting zero results, no matter what I search for (even tried to make the query static and it still didn't work). I have Fulltext indexes on both fields.

What can cause this?

Thanks,

Roy

p.s

The search should fit any length of sting (even short ones)

Comment: How many rows are there in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the indexes. Rebuilding them solved this.

Answer (score 3):

The sql statement makes sense.  I think the problem lies here:

```
urldecode($_REQUEST['term'])
```

There's a note in the PHP Manual regarding this

> Warning
>
> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST
>   are already decoded. Using urldecode()
>   on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST
>   could have unexpected and dangerous
>   results.

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: On that note, it would be wise to learn about escaping input. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

( assuming your query isn't throwing an error )

You might want to check the mysql configs related to full text searching.
For example, by default terms under 4 characters won't matching anything

```
mysql> show variables like 'ft_%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```